# Getting icons indicators point in the right direction

Tags: jquery

I have a nested lists, and every time the list item that has children list is expanded the icon triangle needs to pint down. When it is collapsed the icon needs to point to the right.

Clicking on siblings should expand only that level, but collapse all other. In other words the expand/collapse works correctly, no need to change that. I only need help with the icons.

Here's my js code

```
    $('ul').hide();
    $('#tree').show();

    $('#tree li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.children('ul').find('ul').slideUp().end().slideToggle();
        $(this).find('span.uico').first().toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
        $this.siblings().children('ul:visible').slideUp();

        if ($this.siblings().children('ul:visible')) {
            $(this).find('ui-icon-triangle-1-s').removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one problem:

When you do this line:

```
$this.siblings().children('ul:visible').slideUp();
```

that hides all the `$this.siblings().children('ul:visible')` so that they are no longer visible.

Then, when you do:

```
if ($this.siblings().children('ul:visible')) { /*...*/ }
```

there aren't any more children ul elements visible, so that condition will always be 0.

Comment: Hmm, this may be a part of the problem... Even if I place "IF" condition above the line where I collapse, it does not really work.

Comment: I couldn't do too much without a working fiddle - could you create one?